# AWS S3 bucket with "Requester pays" enabled still gets data transfer costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to configure cross account access to S3 bucket with "Requester Pays" enabled.
Here is the bucket configuration:

[image]

I gave another account access to AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess with a role to external account.
In my dotnet application I used the role to authenticate, and created a GetObjectRequest with the RequestPayer parameter :

```
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = "bucketName", Key = "fileName", RequestPayer = RequestPayer.Requester };
var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest);
```

In fiddler I see the request has the expected header of: x-amz-request-payer: requester
[image]

though in the response object I get null value for the RequestCharged property (also in fiddler I can't see the x-amz-request-charged header).

the actual bills confirms that the charges were on the bucket owner, and not the requester account.

can you please advise? any suggestions on solving this?

Comment: Interesting! How were you able to match the bills to that particular usage? Is it possible that the owning account had _some_ usage of the S3 bucket during the billing period, or was that other account the only account that accessed the buckets during that period?

Comment: The bucket owner account had no prior usage (it's a new account which I only uploaded data to and read from the external account).. any way I don't understand why the GetObjectResponse doesn't contain the x-amz-request-charged header.

Comment: SDK information: "AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.108.4"

Comment: @JohnRotenstein do you have an update on this?

Comment: tried also using the node sdk (version 2.576.0) and the result is the same, setting the `RequestPayer: 'requester'`  parameter in the getObject request also gets undefined in the response.RequestCharged. Also, per this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/the-aws-sdk-for-javascript-now-supports-amazon-s3-requester-pays-buckets/) not setting the RequestPayer in the request should result in 403 error - which is also not the behavior. Can you please provide a working example for using this feature?

Comment: Can you explain further about the IAM Role that you mention? If the bucket is in Account-A and you are wanting to access it from Account-B, where is the IAM Role? If an IAM User in Account-B is assuming a role in Account-A, then they are deemed to be using Account-A, and Account-A would receive the charges.

Comment: The billing part is not documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html), how can I share all S3 buckets with another account using the request payer feature?

Comment: You can share a bucket with another Amazon S3 account by creating a Bucket Policy that grants access to that account. In the principal, specify the other account (eg `"Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"}`. You can activate Requester Pays independently of this. In the other account, make sure that the IAM credentials have permission to access S3, either for all buckets or at least for the bucket being shared. That is, the bucket in Account-A permits Account-B, and the user in Account-B also needs to be granted permission to use S3.